# Approximation of $\left| \ln (1 + \cos x) \right|$

Tags: limits, trigonometry

I'm trying to evaluate $$\lim\limits_{x \to +\infty} \frac{\left|\ln (1+\cos x) \right|}{x}$$
While $\left|\ln(1+\cos x)\right|$ is not convergent, I suppose (in trying to prove that this limit is $0$) that it should be bounded by some $x^r$ where $r < 1$. But I still cannot think of any.

Comment: @SaiMehta I don't think this rule would work, since $\left| ln(1+\cos x \right|$ is divergent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no limit. For every $x=\frac{3\pi}{2}+2k\pi$ your function is undefined and has a vertical asymptote there. No matter how large $x$ is, those infinite spikes keep occurring, so there is no limit.

Comment: I feel ashamed, how can I forgot this. Thank you.